# Creating 3D array from 2D array and Vector in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for an efficient and cleaner way to achieve this as I can easily do this through list comprehension.

I have a large 2D `numpy array` A of shape `20,000x500` and a vector `numpy array` B of shape `20,000`.

I want to concatenate B with each column of A to create a list of length 500 where each element of the list is as follows:

```
np.hstack(A[:, i], B.reshape(-1,1)) where i is in range(0,500)
```

I am currently using list comprehension which makes it appear messy.

Edit:
Output is list of length 500 with each element of list an array of shape 20,000x2

Comment: What's messy about creating a list with a list-comprehension?

Comment: What must be the output array shape?

Comment: If you want a list as output, I guess that list comprehension would be good.